# deploying random forest model from python to android studio

Tags: android-studio, random-forest

I am trying to integrate my random forest model from python to android studio. But I am unable to do it through tensor flow. Can anyone suggest to me any other alternative?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear, post along with your error so communication can help you. BTW, Android Studio is an IDE, why you could not implement your model using python?

Comment: I am trying to convert random forest to a .tflite model so that it can be integrated to an app, but it is showing tensor flow does not have random forest package.

Comment: Also, TensorFlow Decision Forests is only available for Mac and Linux, I am using a windows system.